# Sync files between GCLOUD instances of same group

Tags: linux, networking, rsync, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Have four instances in GCLOUD with SO: Linux (Ubuntu). I have to replicate the files uploaded through ftp to one machine and then to the remaining 3 machines. I have been thinking to use Rsync, but I would like to know if there is another option or configuration integrated in GCLOUD that allows me to do that. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud compute scp` command  permits to copy files or directories between two Google Compute Engine instances.
Here are some examples on how to do this:

The following example copies a file from your workstation to the home directory of the active user on the remote instance.

```
gcloud compute scp [LOCAL_FILE_PATH] [INSTANCE_NAME]:~/
```

or

You can also copy files from an instance to your local workstation by reversing the source and destination variables. The following example copies a file from a remote instance to your workstation.

```
 gcloud compute scp [INSTANCE_NAME]:[REMOTE_FILE_PATH] [LOCAL_FILE_PATH]
```

Also, you can pass a --recurse argument which will recursively copy all files and directories under the specified directory:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse SRC_PATH DEST_PATH
```

Here is the command [reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp).

**N.B: Make sure that each instance that initiates the copy has Compute Engine access scope set to read/write in its configuration.
Also as SSH protocol is used in Gcloud SCP command, there must be a firewall rule that allows SSH access to the remote host**

Other extensive information on [Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it helped, thank you.